# ISPconfig3 creating subdomains

Tags: domain, subdomain

I just started using ISPconfig3. I found out that when I create new subdomain *new.example.com* that it will create subdirectory in domain's directory *example.com*.

So first question I want to ask you if it's possible to create subdomain in a way that it's directory won't be created as subdirectory in domain's directory but as new directory. Like this:

This would be the best if it would be possible to make it like this (it doesn't matter if there is www in the name of those domain directories):

```
/var/www
|--example.com
|  |--www.example.com
|  |  |--public_html
|--example1.com
|  |--www.example1.com
|  |  |--public_html
|  |--sub.example1.com
|  |  |--public_html
|...
```

if not then also like this it would be ok:

```
/var/www
|--example.com
|  |--public_html
|--new.example.com
|  |--public_html
```

I don't want it like this:

```
/var/www
|--example.com
|  |--public_html
|  |--new.example.com
|  |  |--public_html
```

And second question is, whether it's possible to tell ISPconfig somehow NOT to rewrite subdomain from `new.example.com` to `example.com/new`?

I hope I explained it good and you will understand it.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Sites-> Subdomain-> Add New Subdomain`  use `Sites->Add New Website`, enter `sub.example.com` for the domain and ISPconfig will create a subdomain with it's own webspace.

Comment: I assume that is not possible to create my own profiles where I define directory structure how ISPconfig should create directories in /var/www?